# Bash Converter .flac to .wav

Tags: raspberry-pi3

Im a new programmer who bought a raspberry pi 3 and am trying to complete the GPIO music box but have found myself stuck on the converter. 
So far I have this but I keep getting errors after errors.

```
folder = /home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples
for f in folder.flac:
      do echo $mv “$f” “${f%.flac}.wav”
      done
```

I know that my code is not perfect but would like some feed back into how to change this code in order to make all the .flac files inside the specified folder to .wav

Comment: Is the goal to write this in Python?

Comment: @Bart I would need to write it in python

Comment: Then build it up step-by-step. Start with line one (which will give you some syntax errors), when that's working, try to loop over the files you want to convert (I guess the `.flac` files inside `folder`, ignoring other files). Once that is working, think of a way to convert them. When you are completely new to a language, working in baby steps is often the best way to start...

Answer (score 1):

This should work but you need to install avconv.

```
find . -iname "*.flac" | wc

for flacfile in `find . -iname "*.flac"`
do
    avconv -y -f flac -i $flacfile -ab 64k -ac 1 -ar 16000 -f wav "${flacfile%.*}.wav"
done
```